# How to completely teardown database connection and session?

Tags: python, mysql, postgresql, sqlalchemy

When teardown sqlalchemy connection on request, here's current code:

```
def init_request():
    engine = craete_engine(url)
    session = sessionmaker(bind=engine, autoflush=False)

def teardown():
    session.close()
    engine.dispose()
```

Should be engine.dispose() called even after session.close()?
I don't know session.close() is really means teardown database connection.
But about engine.dispose(), this dispose just connection pool not connection(written on document)
http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/connections.html

Answer (score 2):

Closing the session removes all connection resources and gives them back to the pool, see [here](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_basics.html#closing).

> The close() method issues a expunge_all(), and releases any
>   transactional/connection resources. When connections are returned to
>   the connection pool, transactional state is rolled back as well.

If you haven't done anything extra, `create_engine` will establish a pool of connections, see [here](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/pooling.html#connection-pool-configuration).

> The Engine returned by the create_engine() function in most cases has
>   a QueuePool integrated, pre-configured with reasonable pooling
>   defaults.

If you want to liberate the connection after the session is closed (by the way, I wonder why?), I'd suggest you to disable pooling instead (same link, a few paragraphs below); that way you avoid creating the engine every time.

> Disabling pooling using NullPool:

```
from sqlalchemy.pool import NullPool
engine = create_engine(
          'postgresql+psycopg2://scott:tiger@localhost/test',
          poolclass=NullPool)
```